# Persistent TCP connection in DMZ

Tags: firewall, configuration, tcp, dmz

A vendor is requesting to allow persistent tcp (not port 80) connection between a server in the DMZ and the internal network. I don't have much experience with this setting. Can anyone shed some light on disadvantages of allowing persistent connection? Guidance is much apprciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask this question to the vendor to see why *they* want it, and have the explain it to make sure you know what they are talking about.  I am not quite sure, but it sounds like they mean enabling the optional keep alive TCP feature.  Keep-Alive can serve a couple of purposes that I can think of right now:

- Identify a connection that has gone dead and make sure it gets closed in a timely fashion and that the application knows it is gone.  This is probably the reason they want it.
- Keep a session open as long as the other end responded to the probes.  This can save a *little* overhead because you don't have has many session opens and closes (Hand-Shake and FIN). More overhead can be saved if the protocol on top has a fair amount of open close work to do as well.

This is a debated topic, as mentioned in [TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html), many feel keep alive should be handled by the application layer, not the transport layer.